# Import and export files between D365 Business central and VM

Tags: virtual-machine, workflow, power-automate, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I'm working on a project where I've found myself in a situation where i need to import .txt files into d365 business central from a repository in a distant Virtual Machine.
Is it possible to establish such connexion in both ways (export/import).
I've done some research and i think it's impossible to do it using power automate or logic apps, so it would be perfect if you helped me to find another solution that will actually work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have BC on prem and you have access to this VM through your network then you can open and load the file through the File Management codeunit.

If not then you could use the Azure On Premise Data Gateway.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-onprem

You can also store the file in an online storage or make it available through an API, FTP, etc.